# Export test result in html file with selenium

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I use selenium to create my test then i export it to PHPUnit file and i use those commands : 
`java -jar selenium-server.jar` to start server RC
and 
`phpunit test.php` to run script
I need now to save the result into an HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

`phpunit test.php --testdox-html test.html`

And more at [PHPUnit Logging](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.logging)

Comment: This command does not display the test results done by selenium but just a file containing `My test case`

Comment: that file will contain all the results of your phpunit tests, you'll need to take care of the assertions and such so if a test fails it will output some error